# FireStore save document asynchronously in Java Spring Application

Tags: spring, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-run

Per [Java](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#java_1) Example, a document can be written as

```
ApiFuture<WriteResult> future = db.collection("cities").document("LA").set(docData);
// ...
// future.get() blocks on response
System.out.println("Update time : " + future.get().getUpdateTime());
```

but if there is a big document and I do not want to wait(block) on it to finish but want let it finish it in background, I tried using

```
future.get(2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).getUpdateTime()
```

Will it guarantee that the document be written, sometime I am getting following error

> java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Waited 2 nanoseconds for
> TransformFuture@aaac[status=PENDING, info=[inputFuture=
> [com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture@qqqqa5b9],
> function=[com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$ApiFunctionToGuavaFunction@3244n86]]] at
> com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:508)
> at com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get
> (FluentFuture.java:93)

So does the application needs to wait for the write ( set) operation) to finish or Firestore will take care of it? App is running in google cloud Run.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an asynchronous operation, you need to ensure you only send a response to the caller once that asynchronous operation has completed.

See the documentation on [avoiding background activities if CPU is allocated only during request processing](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tips/java#avoid_background_activities_if_cpu_is_allocated_only_during_request_processing), specifically the part about  Spring Boot in there.

Failing to follow this guidance may result in your code getting terminated by Cloud Run before it completes, or you getting charged for code that is longer than is necessary.